# The string contains multiple substrings separated by hyphen('-'). How do I compare the substrings and remove the duplicated substrings?

Tags: mysql

```
|reason_list|
|Accident vehicle-Accident vehicle-Accident vehicle-Body-Front-Front spoiler-ScratchBody|
```

The above reason_list field should not hold duplicated substrings. In this example the Accident vehicle is being repeated. It has to occur just once. How can I achieve that in mysql?

The desired result should be

```
|reason_list|
|Accident vehicle-Body-Front-Front spoiler-ScratchBody|
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I used str_cmp function to compare the substrings but I don't know how to combine that with the length of the string

Comment: I would assume that this is pretty difficult to solve with pure MySQL if you don't know which substrings could occur. On the other hand, this is a good example for data that should be stored in normalized format

Comment: Fix your broken data model, then this can easily be enforced with a unique constraint

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You mean to make the table confirm to 1NF??

Comment: No, I mean convert this to 3NF

Comment: 1NF states that A table should only have single(atomic) valued attributes/columns.